# Does the following sequence converge to a rational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the following binary fractional number
$$
x^{(0)} = \sum_{j=1}^l x_{-j}2^{-j},
$$

And consider now the sequence, which I derived from a problem I have,

$$
x^{(k)} = x^{(k-1)} +2^{-2^{k-1}l} \bar{x}^{(k-1)} \;\; \forall k \geq 1
$$

Basically at each iteration you append to the and the bit complement of the previous string.

Does the solution of the sequence converge to a rational number?
My attempt was trying to unroll the equation and see if there's any pattern I can spot, guessing the solution and then computing the limit. I've also tried to study the behaviour of the recurision at $k \rightarrow +\infty$, but I don't end up with anything useful.

Any suggestion on how I could takle the problem? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It can't converge to a rational number, because its binary expansion is not ultimately periodic.

Comment: I wasn't looking specifically for the answer, but maybe some suggestion on how to prove it. I assumed the best way is by contradiction. However I can't see how to use it, as you said it's not ultimately periodic. But I can't really use the contradiction... can you suggest something?

Comment: I am confused now. I gave you a suggestion on how to tackle the problem, didn't I? You still have to prove that the sequence is not ultimately periodic. (You do know that a rational number has an ultimately periodic binary expansion, right?)

Comment: I know about the property of the ultimately periodic. And I suspected it couldn't be a rational number. So I was trying to assume the number would be ultimately periodic, however I don't know how to use that recursion to show that this is not possible. Is there that I'm asking for a suggestion.